# Zend Framework: Is config.ini read before resource bootstraps?

Tags: zend-framework

I am setting a default timezone (UTC) in my config.ini then in my Bootstrap, if user is logged in, set default timezone (`date_default_timezone_set()`) to the logged in user timezone. So I will have to know which is read 1st. If app config is read later, it will override the value I set in Bootstrap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your .ini file is read before your bootstrap file.